# How to check if Month of the year is January

Tags: java

How to check if the month of the year is January and it will look up to the databse table where if there is December(12) and year/Last year and it will insert to that table when if there's none

example is here but it doesn't work

```
  SimpleDateFormat king = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");
  String M = (king.format(new java.util.Date()));
  String L = M;
  if (L.equals(1)) {
     // then it will check the database table if there is none
     // if the rs.next is false then it will count and insert the last 
     // month and last year patient

  } else() { 
    // if it is not Month of January then it will insert the last month this work 
    // for me but the other is not

  }
```

I just need to know how to check if it month of January I already set my Month to January(1) and it is still not working for me i hope you guys help me

Comment: How are you getting the date?

Comment: @NicholasK looks like today date

Comment: `L.equals(1)`??? `L` is a `String` and `1` is an `Integer` (autoboxed from `int`). They will never be equal.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a `String`. Use

```
if (M.equals("01"))
```

**or** you could parse that `String` back to an `int` like

```
if (Integer.parseInt(M) == 1)
```

**or** you *could* use the [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) API

```
if (Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.JANUARY)
```

But I would prefer the Java 8+ `java.time` class [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) to get the month. Like,

```
if (LocalDate.now().getMonthValue() == 1)
```

**or** (as pointed out by [@Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5221149/andreas) in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53967583/how-to-check-if-month-of-the-year-is-january/53967638?noredirect=1#comment94773030_53967638)) use the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html) enum.

```
if (LocalDate.now().getMonth() == Month.JANUARY)
```

Comment: Thank you for Helping Merry Christmas And Happy new year btw

Comment: You meant `M.equals("01")`, right? Format is `MM`, not `M`.

Comment: Or use `if (LocalDate.now().getMonth() == Month.JANUARY)` is you want to name the month.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, do not use `SimpleDateFormat` anymore, it is long outdated. Use java-8's [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html)  
 instead.

Assuming you are trying to fetch the current date use :

```
LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
now.getMonth().getValue(); // this will return an integer value of the month
```

Comment: Thank you for Helping Merry Christmas And Happy new year btw

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Consider time zone.

```
boolean isCurrentDateInJanuary = 
    ( 
        LocalDate                        // Represent the date-only, without time-of-day and without time zone.
        .now(                            // Capture the current date.
            ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" )  // Specify wall-clock time used by the people of a specific region, a time zone.
        )                                // Returns a `LocalDate` object.
        .getMonth()                      // Extracts one of the twelve `Month` enum objects from the date. Returns a `Month` object.
        .equals( Month.JANUARY )         // Compares our `Month` object to a specific `Month` object, the one for January is our target. Returns a `boolean`.
    ) 
;
```

## Time zone

The other two Answers are correct, but ignore the crucial issue of time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may [change at any moment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault()) during runtime(!), so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the code becomes ambiguous to read in that we do not know for certain if you intended to use the default or if you, like so many programmers, were unaware of the issue.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

With proper date locked in per desired/expected time zone, do as the other Answers suggested. Using the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html) enum is easy.

```
boolean isCurrentDateInJanuary = 
    ( 
        today
        .getMonth()
        .equals( Month.JANUARY ) 
    ) 
;
```